# How can I make soundtracks with one artist sort as soundtracks in iTunes (and iPhone)?

Tags: itunes, music.app, id3-tag

Most of the soundtracks in my iTunes library have the Album Artist tag "Various Artists" and so they all appear together in the V's in Albums view. A few soundtracks have only one artist (composer) or mainly one artist, and they appear in a different location.

For example, the soundtrack for The Incredibles appears with the M's for the artist, Michael Giacchino.

Should I change the Album Artist tag to "Various Artists" to make it sort with the other soundtracks? Maybe I should change the Album Artist tag in all of my soundtracks to "Soundtrack".

Any better ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much figured it out. Just pick a consistent description to use for the **Album Artist** or **Sort Artist** and your albums will group together, while being able to preserve the artist for a specific track. The de facto standard for this seems to be calling it "Various Artists", but there's no reason you can't do whatever suits you, whether that's "Soundtracks" or a specific title for each individual soundtrack album.

[image: example soundtrack sorting options]